# post with twitter application

Tags: php, twitter

I'm new in twitter apps. development 
I want to create a twitter application where people can authenticate and they can also able to post their status with that app with my website link.

any suggestion, tutorial or anything else ???

Sorry I've no codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to authenticate users using Twitter, you can use a guide like:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/

To allow users to update their statuses, use this guide (it includes authentication too):

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

https://dev.twitter.com